# SQL with Oracle - Special Symbols

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SELECT statement that was written to be used with SQLPLUS with an Oracle DB. 
The code works perfectly fine with SQLPlus.

I am trying to understand what this SELECT statement means:

```
SELECT '"' || a1 || '","' || a2 || '","' || b1 || '","' || c1 || '","' || c2 || '","' || c3 || '","' || sum(d1) || '",'
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Specifically, I am trying to understand what the following sequence of symbols means:

```
||
```

&

```
'"'
```

&

```
'","'
```

&

```
'",'
```

Why does the SELECT statement start with '"' ||?
Why does the SELECT portion end with a comma?

What are they for/what are they doing?
What do they equate to?
Where is this from? Is this native to SQLPlus or Oracle? I couldn't find any documentation that described this at all. I have tried MANY google searches but seeing as how I have no idea what they were (and consequently what to search for), it is very hard to find anything on it.

Comment: The parts within single quotes are regular strings, and `||` concatenates them.

Comment: Easy stuff - google up @Jsh562

Comment: Looks like it's a formatting a result set into CSV

Comment: @up_one have you tried googling it? "I couldn't find any documentation that described this at all."
Easy stuff. Read my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ORACLE `||` is used to concatenate strings together, it is the same as SQL-Server `+`

`'"'` & `'","'` & `'",'` is just part of the strings. It is only meant for showing up on output but does not have any meaning.

here is documentation on Oracle Concatenation Operator http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm

> Why does the SELECT statement start with '"' ||?

Just like it was mentioned in comments it is done to surround column with `"` on both sides

> Why does the SELECT portion end with a comma?

That is strange, I would expect it to end with some other character to identify end of the line.

> What are they for/what are they doing?

It is likely that it is special formatting for CSV file.

Comment: thanks for the response! What do you mean by "only meant for showing up on output"?

Comment: When you run that query you will see `"some data","other data"`

Comment: In (standard) SQL the `||` is the string concatenation operator - not only in Oracle. Microsoft simply chose to ignore the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 1):

**See bellow**

- **||** will concatenate strings + data
- ' **"** ' - will print "
- ' **","** ' - will print ","
- ' **",** ' - will print ",

  **Example :**

```
    SQL> select 
    '>>'|| 
    DESCRIPTION_PARAMETER ||
    ' string ' ||
    DESCRIPTION_PARAMETER ||
    ' $%&* '
     from parameters_companies;
```

```
Examples output
======================
>>BASE UTC string BASE UTC $%&*<br>
>>WARRANTY string WARRANTY $%&*<br>
>>BASE UTC string BASE UTC $%&*<br>

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you!
could you explain why the SELECT portion of the statement starts with " + and ends with ", ??? and does starting with a concatenate or ending with a comma have any effect?

Comment: The result will be embed in that " or any other symbol of character you include inside the ' ? '